# bucle me inhabilita codigo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

buscando maneras de controlar el saldo de mi billetera bitcoin ilimitada cantidad de veces, trate este codigo:

```
from mnemonic import Mnemonic
from bip32utils import BIP32Key
from decimal import Decimal
import requests
import re

# Crear un objeto Mnemonic
mnemo = Mnemonic("english")

#################################################################################################################
# Generar una dirección de billetera utilizando BIP-39
seed = mnemo.to_seed('endless guitar wealth horror cute sauce flame horn guide charge relief execute')

# Generar una dirección de billetera utilizando BIP-32
bip32_key = BIP32Key.fromEntropy(seed)

# Generar la direccion bitcoin
addressBTC = bip32_key.Address()
print("Dirección BTC:", addressBTC)

######################################################################################################
responsebtc = requests.get(f'https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/{addressBTC}')
databtc = responsebtc.text
match = re.search(r'''<span class="dash-label">Balance</span><br>
(.*?)
</li>''', databtc)
if match:
    balance = re.search(r"(\d+(?:[.,]\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)?) BTC", match.group(1))
    if balance:
        balancebtc=float(balance.group(1))
        print("Saldo en Bitcoin:", Decimal(balancebtc / 100000000))
    else:
        print("No se encontró el saldo BTC")
else:
    print("No se encontró la etiqueta específica de BTC")
```

la respuesta de este codigo seria:

```
Dirección BTC: 1jVrqsaURnyqJrYTDmmtyyxVapv4CHBEA
Saldo en Bitcoin: 0
```

la modificacion para crear el bucle seria esta:

```
while True:
    ######################################################################################################
    responsebtc = requests.get(f'https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/{addressBTC}')
    databtc = responsebtc.text
    match = re.search(r'''<span class="dash-label">Balance</span><br>
    (.*?)
    </li>''', databtc)
    if match:
        balance = re.search(r"(\d+(?:[.,]\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)?) BTC", match.group(1))
        if balance:
            balancebtc=float(balance.group(1))
            print("Saldo en Bitcoin:", Decimal(balancebtc / 100000000))
        else:
            print("No se encontró el saldo BTC")
    else:
        print("No se encontró la etiqueta específica de BTC")
```

la respuesta del mismo seria la siguiente:

```
Dirección BTC: 1jVrqsaURnyqJrYTDmmtyyxVapv4CHBEA
No se encontró la etiqueta específica de BTC
```

las palabras ahi expuestas son de prueba, hasta ahora he visto y todos los exploradores me ponen un limite de solicitudes(si conocen alguno que no, le agradeceria mucho), lo que me extraño fue que al tratar de crear un bucle con ese codigo, sea la forma que sea que lo creara, automaticamente no me encuentra el saldo BTC de la solicitud, mientras que ejecutando manualmente el codigo 20 veces funciona sin problemas, alguien me aclararia la duda?

Comment: Revisaste lo que devuelve responsebtc.text? Si no devuelve lo habitual, podrías agregar el resultado a la pregunta por favor? quizá no está devolviendo lo que piensas en el segundo ciclo. Quizá solo se acepta cierta cantidad de requests por segundo y, cuando lo haces manualmente, haces solo un request por segundo. Sobre lo de que haya una sin esa limitación, lo dudo, supongo yo que es una cuestión de seguridad para reducir el daño de los ataques de ddos.

Comment: Cualquier sitio decente que recibe mas de X cant de req por segundo, bloquea, porque parece un ataque DDOS

Comment: @DanteS. me devuelve bien todo, siempre devuelve igual, lo encuentre o no, pero cuando hago el bucle ya me da error automaticamente desde la primera vuelta, no es que ei error en la segunda vuelta, eso es lo que meda curiosidad, porque entenderia esos limites, pero me sucede desde que lo ejecuto

Comment: Si es la primera vuelta el problema, eso es extraño. Tal vez podamos ayudarte mejor si proporcionas una muestra de como queda tu código poniendolo en bucle.

Comment: @DanteS. agregue la modificacion que hice para el bucle(tambien lo hice con funciones anidadas y bucle for, todas la misma respuesta)

Comment: Metele un time.sleep() al bucle para que haya una espera entre peticiones. El valor de tiempo a esperar depende de lo que el servidor decida que es "licito" o no.

Comment: @abulafia no cambia nada, me da error desde la primera llamada

Comment: Estás diciendo que se trata exactamente del mismo código, tan solo indentado a la derecha después de un `while True:` y que  ya en la primera iteración te da un error, pero si quitas el while y desindentas ya no lo da? Eso no puede ser. ¿Seguro que es en la primera? Añade un `print("Ejecutado")` justo como primera línea dentro del bucle para comprobar cuántas veces te aparece ese mensaje antes del error.

Comment: @abulafia entiendo, creeme, tambien estoy frustrado, con la prueba que me dices es lo mismo, me devuelve:                                                                                    

Dirección BTC: 1jVrqsaURnyqJrYTDmmtyyxVapv4CHBEA
ejecutado
No se encontró la etiqueta específica de BTC
ejecutado
No se encontró la etiqueta específica de BTC
ejecutado
No se encontró la etiqueta específica de BTC
ejecutado

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con abulafia. Un while no debería de afectar en funcionamiento del código que contiene. El error tiene que suceder en la segunda iteración o algo estás haciendo distinto o estás ante un error interno de Python muy improbable.

Comment: @DanteS. pueden probar el codigo que les pusearriba, veran que funciona sin el bucle y al ponerselo no, al parecer es error de python

Comment: @DanteS. ¡Pues tenía razón el OP! Yo no daba crédito hasta que vi el detalle (facepalm!). Mira mi respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He tenido que probarlo yo mismo porque no me lo creía. Y efectivamente, al poner el código dentro de un `while` ocurrió el problema descrito.

¡Pero que no cunda el pánico! Todo tiene explicación. La culpa no era del `while`, sino de la indentación. Debido a que el cuerpo del bucle ha de ir indentado, se tiene que una parte de ese código se convierte en:

```py
while True:
    # ...omitido
    match = re.search(r'''<span class="dash-label">Balance</span><br>
    (.*?)
    </li>''', databtc)
```

y vemos que debido a esto la cadena que se le está pasando a `re.search()`, al ser una cadena multilínea por ir delimitada por triple `'''`, contiene ahora espacios donde antes no los había (tras el `<br>`), por culpa de lo cual ya no se encuentra el matching.

### Soluciones

La más obvia es quitar los espacios de dentro de la cadena. El código resultante es válido para Python aunque feo para los ojos debido a que parece que la indentación se ha roto dentro del bucle:

```py
while True:
    responsebtc = requests.get(f'https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/{addressBTC}')
    databtc = responsebtc.text
    match = re.search(r'''<span class="dash-label">Balance</span><br>
(.*?)
</li>''', databtc)
    if match:
        balance = re.search(r"(\d+(?:[.,]\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)?) BTC", match.group(1))
        if balance:
            balancebtc=float(balance.group(1))
            print("Saldo en Bitcoin:", Decimal(balancebtc / 100000000))
        else:
            print("No se encontró el saldo BTC")
    else:
        print("No se encontró la etiqueta específica de BTC")
```

Otra solución es no utilizar la triple comilla, sino la comilla normal para que la cadena no ocupe varias líneas, y escribir dentro de ella un `\n` donde queramos retornos de carro. Eso por cierto requiere quitar la `r` de delante de la cadena ya que eso indicaría cadena *raw* en la que el `\` pierde su carácter especial.

```py
while True:
    responsebtc = requests.get(f'https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/{addressBTC}')
    databtc = responsible.text
    match = re.search('<span class="dash-label">Balance</span><br>\n(.*?)\n</li>', databtc)
    if match:
       # ... etc
```

Por último, una solución híbrida. Si quieres partir la cadena en varias líneas de código (porque consideras que es demasiado larga para una línea), pero no quieres utilizar la triple comilla (porque eso introduce problemas debido a la indentación), puedes romper la larga cadena en cadenas más cortas y poner una en cada línea, aprovechándote de que para python cuando aparecen dos cadenas seguidas en el código, sin comas ni otros símbolos entre ellas (`"como" "esto"`) las concatena automáticamente en una sola (`"comoesto"`), aunque aparezcan en líneas separadas, con tal de que ambas estén entre paréntesis como es el caso por ser argumentos de una llamada a función.

Fíjate que el hecho de separarlas en varias líneas no hace que contengan automáticamente los retornos de carro (como sí ocurre en las delimitadas por triple comilla), así que si quieres que los retornos de carro sean parte de la cadena resultante debes ponerlos explícitamente dentro de las comillas. Puedes aprovechar para indentar aún más esas líneas (pues ya no les afecta la indentación) para que quede más claro que son parte de los parámetros de la función.

```
while True:
    responsebtc = requests.get(f'https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/{addressBTC}')
    databtc = responsebtc.text
    match = re.search('<span class="dash-label">Balance</span><br>\n'
                      '(.*?)'
                      '\n</li>', 
                      databtc)
    if match:
       # etc...
```

Esta solución para el intérprete python es exactamente igual a la anterior. Pero para el lector humano puede resultar más agradable al evitar la cadena larga y dar una indicación visual de las tres líneas que se pretende buscar.

**Nota**. Al margen de haber resuelto el problema, sigo opinando que el bucle debe contener un `time.sleep()` para no saturar al servidor con peticiones seguidas, que pueden acabar por disparar un mecanismo de protección que te bloquee.

Comment: Interesante detalle! Es algo difícil de notar. Nunca me gustaron esas cadenas de triple comilla por que justamente toman todos los espacios que están entre las columnas donde empiezan las comillas. Aun así, como podremos ver, el error no era de funcionamiento del while.

Comment: otro detalle mas a estar pendiente siempre, muchas gracias por la explicacion